# Unbind an event from Document with a different seletor

Tags: jquery, events, binding, jquery-selectors

I have the following global click behaviour in my app

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnSubmit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

Now I have a one-off instance where I need a `.btnSubmit` button on a modal window to have a different behaviour. I have two workarounds

1. using a different class
2. adding a data attribute to the button and adding a conditional to my binding above

However, I'd really prefer to just remove the binding, like so

```
$(document).off("click", ".modal.mywindow .btnSubmit")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I guess because the selector is slightly different from the original `".btnSubmit"`

Is there a way to unbind the event from this specific selector without affecting other instances of `".btnSubmit"` on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're correct that the selectors for "off" have to match the ones given in the "on", per the [jQuery docs for .off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

> To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector
>   argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to
>   .on() when the event handler was attached.

If you added some small logic inside of your "on", checking whether or not the clicked button has .modal.mywindow as a parent before submitting, would that be satisfactory? Something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnSubmit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).closest(".modal.mywindow").length <= 0) {
        $(this).parents("form").submit();   
    }
});
```

It's similar to your option number 2, but wouldn't require you to change your HTML.